# Application security of Bitcoin Core

Tags: security, bitcoin-core-development, gitian

Is there any information about how Bitcoin Core has applied [secure development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_security) or [application security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_security) in the past and currently? For example, the inclusion of third-party dependencies must be checked and tracked so that a dependency doesn't contain a vulnerability or an exploit, and the same reasoning about the build system.

Is there any policy and mechanism in practice for secure development and/or testing and verification of the security, including the dependencies and the build system?

I read [somewhere](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.06020.pdf) that early development of Bitcoin Core was done in a "jail" but I couldn't find any other source than the mentioning of it in that specific article:

> To address uncontrolled build inputs, it is tempting to “jail” builds
> into sanitized environments that always present a canonical
> interface to the underlying build system. Indeed, this was the
> approach taken by early projects such as Bitcoin and Tor
> (rbm.torproject.org). However, jails result in slower build times and
> impose technical and social restrictions on developers who may be
> accustomed to choosing their tooling. Most jails cannot address
> non-determinism issues either

Is there any more information about it? Was it a real BSD jail or just an isolated environment to make sure that only the allowed dependencies were included?

Answer (score 0):

The authors of the article most likely referred to a system named Gitian that's been used to check the integrity of Bitcoin builds https://bitcoinmagazine.com/technical/what-is-gitian-building-how-bitcoin-s-security-processes-became-a-model-for-the-open-source-community-1461862937